# Blazor sample app slow loading while develop

Tags: performance, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a new Blazor Web Assembly app from visual studio 2022, and I got the usual template application with a counter button

[image: Blazor sample]

When I run this app from my development machine, the first load take 20 seconds. Every time I change something in the code and re-run the application it takes 20 seconds to load.

Is this the normal behaviour or do I have something wrong on my development machine?

It's very hard to develop something if you have to wait 20 seconds everytime you want to test a modification

Looking at the network tab of the browser I see this:

[image: Blazor Slowliness]

As you can see 21.76 MB of resource are cached, and only 0.04 MB are downloaded from the network. So why does it take so long?

Comment: I have the same problem. It's basically unusable like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find out that the problem is the antivirus used by my company, ESET

Seems that it has some kind of checks that takes 20 seconds to analyze web assembly

I had to completely uninstall the antivirus to avoid the problem